# Link a button to a python function from my model (Odoo 8)

Tags: python, model, odoo, odoo-8

I get trouble linking a button to a function (python) from my model.
I searched on the net but got only few informations for Odoo 8.
That is my code right now:

My function from my model (mymodule.service):

```
def main_val(self, context=None):
     if context is None:
         context = {}
     [...]
```

The view associated:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_myodule_clients_tree">
          <field name="name">mymodule.clients.tree</field>
          <field name="model">mymodule.service</field>
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree"/>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
              <field name="display_name" position="after">
                  <button name="main_val" type="object" string="Bill" class="oe_highlight" /> 
              </field>
          </field>
      </record>
```

I keep having this error:

```
Error details:
Field `function` does not exist
```

and I can't figure out why.

Do you have any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the python function on your button click you must have to set the same method name in your **button name attribute** and **button** **type** attributes as the object.

I will give the small demo with you  just check it with one your hand

```
def main_val(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
     if context is None:
         context = {}
    # your logic will set over  hear
return True
```

you have to set the same name attribute in your xml file with button name attribute

```
<button name="main_val" type="object" string="Bill" class="oe_highlight" />
```

you can check your method arguments and update your module and click the button

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: Thans for your answer but I added "cr, uid, ids" to the parameters and a return statement but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using odoo 8 you can use :

```
@api.one 
def main_val(self)
```

or

```
@api.multi
def main_val(self)
```

[@one](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorator.html#api-one) execute function for this record only
[@muli](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorator.html#api-multi) for set of records